# как выровнять все горизонтали

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я не могу выровнять все го горизонтали. Как сделать что бы текст и иконки были по центру

```
&__contact {
}

&__title {
    color: #000;
}

&__items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

&__item {
}

&__icon {
    max-width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}

&__text {
    position: relative;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На данной площадке принято оставлять код текстом, а так же предоставлять минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `.contacts__item`, дайте свойства:

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: это конечно не помогло, но благодаря вам я вспомнил про align-items в позиции center. Все равно спасибо за внимание)

Comment: Ах да.. При `flex-direction: column;` нужен `align-items`. Поправлю ответ.